# Adding Visual Studio Load Tests to TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2013, teamcity, load-testing

I've create several load tests in VS 2013. They work fine. Now I want to add them to my Continuous Integration process in TeamCity. I've looked in the documentations but didn't find how to automatically run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [you can run them from command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use the MSTest runner in a build step in TeamCity to run them.